# How to solve a special char problem after regex metod

Tags: python, pandas, text, encoding

I've saw a interesting these days to study french with a simple tkinker interface. As i'm studying this libary, i've decide to make my own version, but this time to learn spanish. Before using tkinker it's required a csv document with frequent words. I'm using this doc:

https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords/blob/master/content/2018/es/es_50k.txt

My first goal is filter this txt file and make a csv file without the numbers.  Here I've found my first trouble. When the words pass the "regex filter", some letters "change"

```
import re
from pandas import*
import string

language = "spanish"

list_not_letters = [
     ('&aacute', 'á'), ('&agrave', 'à'), ('&atilde', 'ã'), ('&Atilde', 'Ã'), ('&acirc', 'â'), ('&Acirc', 'Â'), ('&Agrave', 'À'),
    ('&eacute', 'é'), ('&Eacute', 'É'), ('&ecirc', 'ê'), ('&Ecirc', 'Ê'), ('&iacute', 'í'), ('&Iacute', 'Í'),
 ('&oacute', 'ó'), ('&Oacute', 'Ó'), ('&otilde', 'õ'), ('&Otilde', 'Õ'),
 ('&uacute', 'ú'), ('&Uacute', 'Ú'), ('&ugrave', 'ù'), ('&Ugrave', 'Ù'),
 ('&ccedil', 'ç'), ('&Ccedil', 'Ç'),  ('&ntilde', 'ñ'), ('&Ntilde', 'Ñ')
]

alfabeth = string.ascii_lowercase

words_list = [language]
with open("es_50k.txt", "r") as file:
    words = file.read()
    words = words.split() # split the lines using spaces as parameter

for word in words:
        if word == re.sub('[0-9]', '', word): # verify if word contains number
           word.split() #divide the word in letters
           for letter in word:
               if letter not in alfabeth: # verify if it is a letter
                   especial_letter = letter # if it's not a letter, so it's a especial char.
                   index_letter = list_not_letters.index(especial_letter)# use it to find the index in the non letters list
                   letter.replace(list_not_letters[index_letter][1], list_not_letters[index_letter][0])# replace the first value of the tuple for the second
           word = ''.join(word)
           words_list.append(word)
    data_list = DataFrame(words_list)
    data_list.to_csv('only_words.csv', index=False)
```

Trying to solve the trouble, I've created a list with tuples, when the first item is the "strange character" and the second is what it should be in the csv. After that, I've read all, trying to make it organized and comment, part by part to make sure it wasn't a typo problem.

the last error message i had was that:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\word_guide\main.py", line 27, in 
index_letter = list_not_letters.index(especial_letter)# use it to find the index in the non letters list
ValueError: 'Ã' is not in list

---

Even knowing where the problem lives i still don't know how to solve it. I've a lots of nice post here, tryed some ideas from yt videos but till now none of them works.

Comment: I do not see where the regex issue is here. It seems to me as text file encoding issue. You use `with open("es_50k.txt", "r") as file:`, maybe you need to specify the exact encoding? Try `with open("es_50k.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:` or `with open("es_50k.txt", "r", encoding="latin1") as file:`, etc.

Comment: `word.split() #divide the word in letters` is a "meme", remove this line, it does nothing in your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using the "encoding="utf-8" solve the question. Thank you so much for your help!